how to encrypt and decrypt a column data in oracle without using dbms_crypto
hello i need to know a WAY to encrypt and decrypt data without using dbms_crypto package in oracle because i need to grant execute on this package and i cannot have this permission so if there's any built in function that can do this i tried encrypt & decrypt but it only work in sql server i also tried standard_hash(col,'MD5') but it was encryption only no decryption

MD5 is a hash function, there is nothing to encrypt and decrypt! Apart from that, all hash and encryption algorithms in DBMS_CRYPTO are are open/public. Should be possible to use almost any other programming language.

... including in Java stored procedures if you are allowed those, or an external call, if it has to be initiated from with the DB. Depends what restrictions you have. It'll be easier if you can do it outside the database those, in your application that connects to Oracle.

This whole idea that  dbms_crypto is "dangegous" is nonsense. These security "experts" who insist on revoking this, simply do no understand the topic. If you need this package for businesses logic, it should be granted to you.
Otherwise you might be able to overcome it by using java stored procedure.

Go back to your DBAs and insist they give you exec rights on dbms_crypto. It's ridiculous that they wouldn't.

It is equally important to understand what you are encrypting, and why. An improper implementation of dbms_crypto can give you a false sense of security.

Perhaps something like this:


/* encrypt and decrypt */

CREATE TABLE encryption_values 
(
  NAME   VARCHAR2(100 BYTE),
  VALUE  NVARCHAR2(100)
);

INSERT INTO encryption_values
   SELECT 'key' NAME,
          RAWTOHEX ('52AB32;^$!ER94988OPS3W21') VALUE
     FROM DUAL
   UNION
   SELECT 'iv' NAME, RAWTOHEX ('TY54ABCX') VALUE FROM DUAL;

SELECT * FROM encryption_values


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION F_ENCRYPT (p_input VARCHAR2)
   RETURN VARCHAR2
AS
   v_encrypted_raw     RAW (2000);
   v_key               RAW (320);
   v_encryption_type   PLS_INTEGER
      :=   DBMS_CRYPTO.DES_CBC_PKCS5;
   v_iv                RAW (320);
BEGIN
   SELECT VALUE
     INTO v_key
     FROM encryption_values
    WHERE name = 'key';
   SELECT VALUE
     INTO v_iv
     FROM encryption_values
    WHERE name = 'iv';
   v_encrypted_raw :=
      DBMS_CRYPTO.encrypt (src   => UTL_I18N.STRING_TO_RAW (p_input, 'AL32UTF8'),
                           typ   => v_encryption_type,
                           key   => v_key,
                           iv    => v_iv);
   RETURN UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2 (UTL_ENCODE.base64_encode (v_encrypted_raw));
END;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION F_DECRYPT (p_input VARCHAR2)
   RETURN VARCHAR2
AS
   v_decrypted_raw     RAW (2000);
   v_key               RAW (320);
   v_encryption_type   PLS_INTEGER := DBMS_CRYPTO.DES_CBC_PKCS5;
   v_iv                RAW (320);
BEGIN
   SELECT VALUE
     INTO v_key
     FROM encryption_values
    WHERE name = 'key';
   SELECT VALUE
     INTO v_iv
     FROM encryption_values
    WHERE name = 'iv';
   v_decrypted_raw :=
      DBMS_CRYPTO.DECRYPT (
         src   => UTL_ENCODE.base64_decode (UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW (p_input)),
         typ   => v_encryption_type,
         key   => v_key,
         iv    => v_iv);
   RETURN UTL_I18N.RAW_TO_CHAR (v_decrypted_raw, 'AL32UTF8');
END;

SELECT 'pugzly' INPUT, 
        F_ENCRYPT('pugzly') ENCRYPTED_RESULT,     F_DECRYPT(F_ENCRYPT('pugzly')) DECRYPT_RESULT 
FROM DUAL;


